# Transfer Data from Database to Leaflet POP UP

Tags: javascript, leaflet, php, html

How can I show data from a database to leaflet in a pop up?

Here is my code in php select command:

```
<?php 
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=poi', 'root', ''); 
$sql = "SELECT name,user_date,user_time,address,lat,lng,icon_name FROM tblmarker"; 

$rs = $db->query($sql); 
if (!$rs) { 
    echo "An SQL error occured.\n"; 
    exit; 
} 

$rows = array(); 
while($r = $rs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
    $rows[] = $r; 
    $name[] = $r['name'];
    $user_date[] = $r['user_date'];
    $user_time[] = $r['user_time'];
    $address[] = $r['address'];
    $icon_name[] = $r['icon_name'];
} 
print json_encode($rows); 
$db = NULL; 
?>
```

and here is my code in showing the marker in the map from database:

```
function getInfo() { 
        $.getJSON("get_info.php", function (data) { 
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
            var location = new L.LatLng(data[i].lat, data[i].lng); 
            var marker = new L.Marker(location,{icon:Icon1}); 
            var ll = marker.getLatLng();

          marker.bindPopup("$name<br>$user_date<br>$user_time<br>$address<br>$icon_name").addTo(map); 

             } 
        }); 
      }
```

I thought it works because when I refresh it the marker from my database shows in the map but when I click the marker for the pop up the pop up shows only is like this.

```
$name
$user_date
...
```

What's wrong with my code? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

The popup is printing the text just as you have written it. Use javascript variables in marker.bindPopup, not php:

```
marker.bindPopup(data[i].name + "<br>" + data[i].user_date + "<br>" + data[i].user_time + "<br>" + data[i].address + "<br>" + data[i].icon_name).addTo(map);
```